# What does "vamos the ranch" mean in this Mark Twain short story?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, mark-twain

What does this sentence from "Double Barrelled Detective Story" by Mark Twain mean?

> "If I was running this shop I'd make him say something, some time or other, or vamos the ranch."

In Spanish, 'Vamos' means 'let's go' as far as I know. However I couldn't quite get what Twain was trying to say.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While *vamos* in Spanish does mean "let's go!", it took on another meaning in America, and later on a different spelling: [***vamoose***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vamoose)

> *intransitive verb*
>
> :  to depart quickly
>
> In the 1820s and '30s, the American Southwest was rough-and-tumble
>   territory—the true Wild West. English-speaking cowboys, Texas Rangers,
>   and gold prospectors regularly rubbed elbows with Spanish-speaking
>   vaqueros in the local saloons, and a certain amount of linguistic
>   intermixing was inevitable. One Spanish term that caught on with
>   English speakers was vamos, which means "let's go." Cowpokes and dudes
>   alike adopted the word, at first using a range of spellings and
>   pronunciations that varied considerably in their proximity to the
>   original Spanish form. But when the dust settled, the version most
>   American English speakers were using was vamoose.

Given the time, Mark Twain probably still used the original spelling, but with the new meaning, so what he wrote means:

> "If I was running this shop I'd make him say something, some time or
>   other, or [exit] the ranch."

I don't know the context, but presumably the character being talked about doesn't talk much and the speaker doesn't like that and wants to make him leave the ranch.